# Nivo Slider not loading correctly in Wordpress Theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, nivo-slider

Website: http://notsofastfoodtruck.com/

As you can see the Nivo Slider images load but they do not work, as they stay static.

Console errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'anim_progressbar' script.js:164
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider' script.js:80
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'
```

Any advice to point me in the right direction is appreciated. I'm trying to figure this problem out for a friend.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems. There are seveeral exceptions complaining about unknown methods (nivoSlider, anim_progressbar) on the jQuery object.

here's what I found.

[image]

1. you are including multiple versions of jquery into your page. This will cause trouble. For one of them you have called `.NoConflict()`, which defines the jQuery object.  For the other you have not, which defines the `$` object.  The anim_progressbar is getting defined on one of them (`jQuery`) and you are trying to use it from the other, which throws an exception. You can see it in the screen snip above. Solution: use only one version of jQuery.
2. It appears to me that you are trying to call `nivoSlider()` from outside the document ready function.
3. There's a bunch of other sloppy stuff in script.js.   Like completely empty document.ready blocks.

Basically you need to get your page under control.  It looks like you just threw everything into that page that you could think of. There are 72 scripts, and several instances of jQuery.  Cut it all back and get control of it. start over. Use one version of JQuery.

Then make sure you call `nivoSlider` within `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: This was purchased theme on themeforest.net, i guess i'll have to go through this developer's code and see if i can tidy it up, i have got no responses back from him, but got my money  refunded. hopefully i can figure it out :(

Comment: I'm surprised people make money selling that kind of product.